# Events not firing in subview

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a simple scenario, with a view responsible for managing one of my app areas, called TransactionView. One of its subviews it's called TransactionEditorView.

***The problem with it is that its events are not firing!***

The transaction editor shows correctly (showAddEntryForm is called), but cannot be hidden ('click .hide-add-entry' is never fired).

I will post relevant parts of my code:

**TransactionView.js**

```
Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'transactionView',

    initialize: function() {

        //  ...

        this.editorView = new TransactionEditorView({
            collection: this.collection, 
            parent: this
        });

        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {

        this.$el.html( template() ); // underscore template "transactions.html"

        this.$el.find('.new-transaction').after( this.editorView.render().el );
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click .new-transaction button': 'showAddEntryForm'
    },

    showAddEntryForm: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(event.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
        this.editorView.show(); 
    },
    //...
}
```

**transactions.html**

```
<div class="controls-container">

    <div class="new-transaction">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success add-positive-entry">
            <span class="visible-xs-* hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">+</span>
        </button> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger add-negative-entry">
            <span class="visible-xs-* hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">-</span>
        </button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="balance">balance</div>

    <div class="filters">filters</div>

</div>

<div class="entry-list"></div>
```

**TransactionEditor.js**

```
Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'add-entry-form', 
    template: template, 

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection = options.collection;
        this.parent = options.parent;
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.el);
        this.$el.html( this.template() );
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click .add-entry' : 'addEntry',
        'click .hide-add-entry' : 'hide'
    },

    hide: function(event) {
        console.log("Hiding editor");
        event.preventDefault();
        this.$el.slideUp();
        this.parent.$el.find('.new-transaction button').removeClass('selected');
    },

    show: function() {
        this.$el.slideDown();
    },

    addEntry: function() {

    }
    // ...
}
```

**transactionEditor.html**

```
<form role="form">
    form fields
</form>
```

I suspect that something related to the **el** of the subview is not working good, but can't get where it is... please help me.

***UPDATE***

Very strange! By simply moving the editor view creation code `( this.editorView = new TransactionEditorView(...); )` from the parent's **initialize** method to the parent's render method... It works! Now I'm really confused...

Comment: Any chance of seeing a stripped down (yet functional) demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: No sorry, it wouldn't be simple for me now

Comment: Are you saying anything like `parentView.el.html(...)` anywhere? Are you destroying and re-creating views as needed (good) or trying to re-use views by hiding/showing them (very error prone)?

Comment: My editor view doesn't need to be re-created each time I render the main transaction view, so I create it once in the parent view, render once in the parent's render by adding its el content after a dom element, finally show/hide it as needed? What's wrong?

Comment: Does the parent view ever getting recreated and then the existing editor added to it? I could probably point out the problem if I could see it in action. If you call `$x.html(y)`, then **all** events on **everything** inside `$x` will be removed before the HTML is replaced; so if the editor view is inside `$x` then its event bindings will be gone even though you re-add it. I recommend that you create and destroy views, they should be cheap enough that trying to reuse them is false laziness.

Comment: Hey I just tried to recreate your issue and it works good, here is jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/fvyad63b/ the one thing I noticed it was that you have no buttons for events with classes `.add-entry` and `.hide-add-entry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing a

```
events: {
  "all": "log"
}

log: function(e) {
  console.log e;
}
```

That should log out every event that's getting fired. I find it super helpful when troubleshooting.